# Implementing subscription based in app purchase

Tags: iphone, ios4, in-app-purchase, subscription

Having the below questions on implementing the in app purchase - Subscription based.
I would like to sell songs into my iPhone app via subscription based buying.
Here we do these things as below

-- We categorize songs , and list it. we will be having the category like "LOVE,SAD,PATRIOTIC,FRIENDSHIP,etc".

-- All of these content will be fetched from the web-server.

-- For each category , we have subscription.

-- When the user taps on "Subscribe", we show list of available subscription as "Monthly, weekly,Daily"

-- once the user completes the payment , we sent request to web server and download the content

-- This is my intended behavior of my proposed iPhone app

I am having the below questions
- Do i need to register ( product id ) each Songs into the iTunes developer portal.

- also if the new song get added to the we server, do i need to add that new song product id into the iTunes
- Pls let me know how can i go with implementing for the above situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, When you create categorize like SONGS then for that you are giving option like monthly, yearly etc.

In the itunes, when you create a main category like SONGS then you have an option to create child category means subcategory so you can include that new songs in the SONGS category.

But yes if you add a new song you have to create a new product ID for that because for the in-app purchase product id is required for any purchase.

if you add new song on server how would apple know so you have to add this also in Product id list.

let me know if you have any further query.